# Missing 'shelljs' for Cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

In VS2015, when I try to deploy an app to my Android device, I am getting this message:

"Error : BLD00401 : Could not find module 'shelljs'. Please Go to Tools     -->    Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again"

The app works fine in the Ripple emulator and as a Windows10 app. Have tried clearing the Cordova cache, and also installing 'shelljs' using 'npm install -g shelljs' but the problem persists. This is a new install of Windows10 with a new install of VS2015

[Later]. With the same project on VS2015RC and Windows7, the app installs on to the android device with no problems. I want to make sure the Win10 system works before upgrading my desktop PC from Win7 to Win10

Answer (score 0):

Seems I had an incompatible version of Cordova specified. I changed the 'taco.json' file to reference version 4.3.0 instead of 5.1.1 and I can now install on my phone.
I'm still puzzled how this happened because the whole project was moved via github, and my repo there includes the correct version of taco.json